# connect Python to MYSQL, obtain SP500 symbols

Tags: python, mysql, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The code is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# insert_symbols.py
#table name should be 's_master', password should be '*******', user name should be 's_user'

from __future__ import print_function

import datetime
from math import ceil

import bs4
import MySQLdb as mdb
import requests


def obtain_parse_wiki_snp500():
    """
    Download and parse the Wikipedia list of S&P500 
    constituents using requests and BeautifulSoup.

    Returns a list of tuples for to add to MySQL.
    """
    # Stores the current time, for the created_at record
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    # Use requests and BeautifulSoup to download the 
    # list of S&P500 companies and obtain the symbol table
    response = requests.get(
        "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies"
    )
   # soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text) ///this is the original version, i replaced with the code below
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

    # This selects the first table, using CSS Selector syntax
    # and then ignores the header row ([1:])
    symbolslist = soup.select('table')[0].select('tr')[1:]

    # Obtain the symbol information for each 
    # row in the S&P500 constituent table
    symbols = []
    for i, symbol in enumerate(symbolslist):
        tds = symbol.select('td')
        symbols.append(
            (
                tds[0].select('a')[0].text,  # Ticker
                'stock', 
                tds[1].select('a')[0].text,  # Name
                tds[3].text,  # Sector
                'USD', now, now
            ) 
        )
    return symbols


def insert_snp500_symbols(symbols):
    """
    Insert the S&P500 symbols into the MySQL database.
    """
    # Connect to the MySQL instance
    db_host = 'localhost'
    db_user = 's_user'
    db_pass = '*******'
    db_name = 's_master'
    con = mdb.connect(
        host=db_host, user=db_user, passwd=db_pass, db=db_name
    )

    # Create the insert strings
    column_str = """ticker, instrument, name, sector, 
                 currency, created_date, last_updated_date
                 """
    insert_str = ("%s, " * 7)[:-2]
    final_str = "INSERT INTO symbol (%s) VALUES (%s)" % \
        (column_str, insert_str)

    # Using the MySQL connection, carry out 
    # an INSERT INTO for every symbol
    with con: 
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.executemany(final_str, symbols)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    symbols = obtain_parse_wiki_snp500()
    insert_snp500_symbols(symbols)
    print("%s symbols were successfully added." % len(symbols))
```

The error message I got is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "insert_symbols.py", line 86, in <module>
    insert_snp500_symbols(symbols)
  File "insert_symbols.py", line 81, in insert_snp500_symbols
    cur.executemany(final_str, symbols)
  File "/home/haolun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 285, in executemany
    r = self._query(qs)
  File "/home/haolun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 378, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "/home/haolun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 341, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/haolun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 280, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 's_master.symbol' doesn't exist")
```

I don't know why I am getting this _"mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 's_master.symbol' doesn't exist") message. I did create the s_master table. Is there anything wrong with beautifulsoup commend or anything else?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I don't know why I am getting this _"mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 's_master.symbol' doesn't exist") message. I did create the s_master table. Is there anything wrong with beautifulsoup commend or anything else? Thanks Klaus!

Comment: @Klaus D. please check my question above. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @KlausD. the relevent link is here with beautifulsoup updated.  https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Securities-Master-Database-with-MySQL-and-Python

Comment: Update your question instead of using comments tagged to me.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder. I did update the question. This is my first time using stackoverflow...

Comment: `s_master` is the name of the database. The table named `symbol` was probably not created.

Comment: @RedBaron  I think symbol has been created, mysql> USE s_master;
Database changed
    mysql> CREATE TABLE ‘symbol‘ (
    -> ‘id‘ int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> ‘exchange_id‘ int NULL,
    -> ‘name‘ varchar(255) NULL,
    -> ‘sector‘ varchar(255) NULL,
    -> ‘currency‘ varchar(32) NULL,
    -> ‘created_date‘ datetime NOT NULL,
    -> ‘last_updated_date‘ datetime NOT NULL,
    -> PRIMARY KEY (‘id‘),
    -> KEY ‘index_exchange_id‘ (‘exchange_id‘)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table '‘symbol‘' already exists

Comment: @RedBaron Interesting, when I use show tables, I saw 'symbol' in the s_master list, however, when I use SELECT * FROM symbol, it says ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 's_master.symbol' doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't create the table correctly.I write a sql file `init.sql`, and import it to the mysql database by using the following command:

```
mysql -u root -p < init.sql
```

This is the content of the init.sql

```
create database if not exists s_master default charset utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;
-- chage the password to 123456
grant all on s_master.* to s_user@'localhost' identified by '123456';
use s_master;
create table if not exists symbol(
    ticker varchar(40),
    instrument varchar(40),
    name varchar(40),
    sector varchar(40),
    currency varchar(40),
    created_date datetime,
    last_updated_date datetime
);
```

After that I was able to run your program correctly, the result of the program is:

```
➜ /tmp [sof]$ python yourprogram.py
(u'MMM', 'stock', u'3M Company', u'Industrials', 'USD', datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 26, 5, 24, 11, 62336), datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 26, 5, 24, 11, 62336))
505 symbols were successfully added.
➜ /tmp [sof]$
```

Comment: The problem now is that I can't delete the TABLE 'symbol' because it's a ghost table. SHOW TABLES is showing there is table name 'symbol', but I can't SELECT nor DROP the table

Comment: Sorry, I donnot know the ghost table.

I think you can delete all the database, if there is noimport data.
Or you can  create another databse called s_master2.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Just one last question, how could I create the init.sql file in Ubuntu like you did? I am having all sorts of .frm and .ibd files under mysql folder. But i can't create a sql type file in the folder. Are u using a text editor or anything else?

Comment: `vim init.sql`, and type some sql statement.

If you don not know what are you doing, DO NOT change the file in mysql folder(/var/lib/mysql).

Comment: I finally fixed everything. Thank you all for the help!